# Inserting braces around selection without replacing the selection in Webstorm

Tags: webstorm

While editing JavaScript, I'd like to select a phrase in the code and wrap it with braces.

In Sublime Text for example, the default behavior is when I hit the `[` key with a `piece_of_text` selected, it gets converted to `[piece_of_text]`. However in Webstorm it turns into `[]`.

How do I change this behavior?

Comment: Do you have `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Surround selection on typing quote or brace` option enabled?

Comment: It wasn't enabled, and yep that does the trick. Please post an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure that `Surround selection on typing quote or brace` option is enabled in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys`.